# validateJarFile(servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded in tomcat using eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

> [Tomcat] validateJarFile(servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded.
>   Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile INFO:
>   validateJarFile(\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not
>   loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:
>   javax/servlet/Servlet.class.

I googled for this,I got to know that I am using servlet-api.jar in my project WEB-INF/lib, and also I am having same servlet-api.jar in tomcat/lib folder. so I have to remove servlet-api.jar, But if I remove that jar, I am getting error in import javax.servlet.*; so how to I solve this, help me for fix this error.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error you are getting is because servlet-api needs to be on compile time build path, at runtime your app will have the servlet-api available from tomcat/lib

So add it to your build path simply, In short `servlet-api` is required at compile aswell as runtime

Comment: can u plz tel how to add it to build path

Comment: Which IDE you are using?, Is it maven project (pom) ?

Comment: select proejct > right click > properties > java build path > add external jars > browse to your servlet-api from your local file system > press OK > refresh the project

Comment: But while running my local host.. I am getting 404 error now.. what i do for this now

Comment: I am getting this waring now ..      WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:QRCode' did not find a matching property.
Jun 12, 2012 1:46:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

Comment: @JigarJoshi I did that but the problem is not yet solved, I am using eclipse Juno and tomcat 7.. Inside <webapp> tab of web.xml I have version 2.4..

Comment: i m having jar in build path but getting the same exception. can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 11):

Try this to remove the warning message you were getting.

- The Servlet specs say you are not allowed to have `servlet.jar` in your webapps `lib` directory.
- If you want to get rid of the warning simply remove servlet.jar from

---

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\YOUR_project\WEB-INF\lib
```

Comment: +1 - trying to start hudson-3.0on tomcat 7 was causing this error message. I renamed the servlet jar in the hudson app to servlet.jar.hide and that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: This worked.  Thank you @paul and @Lucky!