# tomcat error deploying war

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I developed a springboot war file to deploy into server, but due to some reason I have to deploy it inside the tomcat of xampp but I am getting error as below. How can I fix this ?

> INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\ipf-2.0.0.RC2\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   Mar 21, 2018 5:19:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>   INFO: validateJarFile(C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\ipf-2.0.0.RC2\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.28.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
>   Mar 21, 2018 5:19:58 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
>   WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
>   Mar 21, 2018 5:20:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
>   SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/ipf-2.0.0.RC2/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar!/] for annotations
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:55)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:175)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validateJarFile(servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded in tomcat using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992644/validatejarfileservlet-api-jar-jar-not-loaded-in-tomcat-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with the tomcat of Xampp. But my problem solved after deploying inside a tomcat v9 that I have downloaded